# Getting the height of video control

Tags: javascript, html5-video

Is there any way we can get the height of the HTML5 video control panel?
In different browsers, this control panel looks different.

[image]

Comment: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/building-custom-controls-for-html5-videos

Answer (score -1):

You could inspect the element. Get his **id / class** and then do this :

```
var elemHeight = $('elemId or class').height();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But the height() will return the height of the video. I want the height of control panel which lies on the bottom of the video and which contains the play/pause button and scrollbar and volume button.

Comment: Yes you just have to get the bar id / class. And `elem.height()` this